# Taking HTML and changing to CSS to override plugin

Tags: html, css

I have the code for HTML and the developer of the plugin said to create a file which I have to change some of the wording the customer sees.  I found the code in HTML (via firebug) and put it in the form but its not working so I am think I need to change more of it into CSS.  This is what I have so far but again it didn't change anything.
I just want the wording to change instead of unlimited content just unlimited etc.

Thank you for any help.

```
<div class="fee-options-for-category">
<table class="fee-options">
<thead>
<tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="fee-option fee-id-1">
<td class="fee-selection">
<input id="wpbdp-fees-radio-1" type="radio" data-canrecur="0"     checked="checked" value="1" name="fees[91]">
</td>
<td class="fee-label">
<label for="wpbdp-fees-radio-1">Basic Listing</label>
</td>
<td class="fee-amount"> — </td>
<td class="fee-duration"> Unlimited </td>
<td class="fee-images"> 0 </td>
</tr>
<tr class="fee-description fee-id-1">
<td></td>
<td colspan="4">✓ put as much a you want.</td>
</tr>
<tr class="fee-option fee-id-2">
<td class="fee-selection">
<input id="wpbdp-fees-radio-2" type="radio" data-canrecur="1" value="2" name="fees[91]">
</td>
<td class="fee-label">
<label for="wpbdp-fees-radio-2">Featured Listing</label>
</td>
<td class="fee-amount"> $ 12.95 </td>
<td class="fee-duration"> 365 days </td>
<td class="fee-images"> 5 </td>
</tr>
<tr class="fee-description fee-id-2">
<td></td>
<td colspan="4">
✓ Unlimited content .
<br>
✓ Ratings support.
<br>
✓ Ability to attach files to your listing.
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

thank you in advance

Susan

Comment: Your question is very confusing and I am not sure what you are specifically asking for. You talk about 'wording', a form, and a plugin but do you know what any of this does? Sounds like you're using Word Press you [may be better off asking the question there...](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I guess I am asking how would I code this for CSS instead of HTML.  I am using WordPress and I want to change the wording that shows up in the table (unlimited, 365 etc) so I asked the plugin developer and the they just told me to override the html with CSS.   I tried but it doesn't seem to work.  (what I did is above).   I will go ask over there sorry about that.

Comment: No need to apologize :) I figured if you posted your question on the other form and mentioned the plugin there may be other people that have had your similar problem and have found a way to fix it.